# QApplication,QClipboard,mimedataで、貼り付けをした後にデータを復元すると、必ずテキストが黒くなる。

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

自分のソフト外の適当なウェブサイトなどから、文章をコピペして、
それをテキストエディタで保存して、再度復元したいと思っています。
例えばなのですが、このサイトからタイトル部分をコピペしてきました。
 [Matahari Wikipedia](https://id.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matahari)

[image]

すると、こんな感じになります。
[image]

Key_1を押して、その内容をセーブしました。

その後、再起動を行い、前のデータを復元してみました。

[image]

すると、常に、ロードしたテキストは真っ暗になります。

mimedata.html()を調べてみますと、

```
<!--StartFragment--><span style="display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: transparent; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Linux Libertine&quot;,&quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;Times&quot;,serif; font-size: 28.8px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 37.44px; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">Matahari</span><!--EndFragment-->
```

色のところが、 (0,0,0).　つまり、黒色がデフォルトで指定されています。
だから、この部分を書き換えればいいじゃないかと思ったんで、

```
clipboard = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()                         
html = clipboard.mimeData().html()
print(html)
html = html.replace("color: rgb(0, 0, 0);","color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
clipboard.mimeData().setHtml(html)




<!--StartFragment--><span style="display: inline !important; float: none; background-color: transparent; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: &quot;Linux Libertine&quot;,&quot;Georgia&quot;,&quot;Times&quot;,serif; font-size: 28.8px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 37.44px; orphans: 2; text-align: left; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; white-space: normal; word-spacing: 0px;">Matahari</span><!--EndFragment-->
```

プリント文で打ちだしたら、確かに（２５５，２５５，２５５）になり、
白になっているはずなのですが、こうして、再度書き換えたhtmlの内容をセットして、再度ロードしてみましたが、結果は相変らずでした。

背景が真っ黒にならないようにしたいのですが、どうすればいいんでしょうか？

こちらが、実行可能なサンプルコードです。

```
from PySide import QtGui

from PySide import QtCore
import sys
import os
class TextEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(TextEdit,self).__init__(parent=None)
    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_1:
            self.save()
            return
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_2:
            self.load()
            return
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_V:
            self.copy_paste()
            return
        return QtGui.QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self,event)
    def save(self):
        print(os.getcwd()+"copy_paste_test.dat")
        file = QtCore.QFile(os.getcwd()+"copy_paste_test.dat")
        file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadWrite)
        out = QtCore.QDataStream(file)
        out.writeQString(self.toHtml())
        file.close()
    def load(self):
        file = QtCore.QFile(os.getcwd()+"copy_paste_test.dat")
        file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        out = QtCore.QDataStream(file)
        self.insertHtml(out.readQString())
        file.close()
    def copy_paste(self):

        clipboard = QtGui.QApplication.clipboard()
        self.insertFromMimeData(clipboard.mimeData())      

def main():
    try:
        QtGui.QApplication([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    textedit = TextEdit()
    textedit.show()
    sys.exit(QtGui.QApplication.exec_())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

実行環境；PySide 1.2.4 Python 3.6.5 Windows10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下が関係しているかもしれません。

[QTextEdit doesn't respect transparency of textBackgroundColor in toHtml() method](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-21522)

Qt5で修正されているようです。

そのため、無理矢理対応するのであれば、以下のように`background-color`の`transparent`を白に置換してやる必要があると思います。

```
html = html.replace("background-color: transparent;","background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
```

一方、CSSの`color`のカラープロパティは文字色を意味するため、背景色を白にする場合は、置換不要です。

Comment: 正確には、save()メソッドの中の、toHtml()をプリント文で打ち出してみたところ、background-color:#000000;で保存されるようになっていました。そのため、background-color;#FFFFFF;にリプレイスしたところ、正常にうちだせるようになりました。ただ回答は非常にヒントになりました。ありがとうございました。